# How can I get the HTTP status and Location header in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, header

I'm new to Perl but need to use it on a project I'm working on. What I need to do is check to see if a URL has a 301 redirect and if it has, get the location. The following told me the code but not the location:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
$ua->max_redirect(0);

my $response = $ua->get('http://www.actwebdesigns.co.uk/');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->status_line;
    print $response->progress;
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

does anyone know how to get the location?

Regards,

Phil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$response->header` method comes from [HTTP::Headers](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Headers) and allows you to inspect the specific headers returned from your request. To find the `Location` header, use

```
my $loc = $response->header( 'Location' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the headers contained in `HTTP::Response` ([`HTTP::Header`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Headers)), with `$response->header`.